# Setting a classes' properties from NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I'm encrypting my entire query string on one page, then decrypting it on another.  I'm getting a NameValueCollection of all the values using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString.

Now, I have a class whose properties match the query string variable names.  I'm struggling how to set the value of the properties from the query string.

Here is my code in progress:

```
        NameValueCollection col = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(decodedString);
        ConfirmationPage cp = new ConfirmationPage();

        for(int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
        {
            Type type = typeof(ConfirmationPage);
            FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(col.GetKey(i));               

        }
```

I'm seeing samples of retrieving values through reflection -  but I'd like to get  a reference to the property of the ConfirmationPage class and set it with it's value in the loop - col.Get(i).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably go the other way and find the properties (or fields using GetFields())
and look them up in the query parameters rather than iterate over the query parameters. You can then use the SetValue method on the PropertyInfo object to set the value of the property on the ConfirmationPage.

```
var col = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(decodedString);
var cp = new ConfirmationPage();

foreach (var prop in typeof(ConfirmationPage).GetProperties())
{
    var queryParam = col[prop.Name];
    if (queryParam != null)
    {
         prop.SetValue(cp,queryParam,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: var prop is throwing error "implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized" - What object is prop actually supposed to be?

Comment: foreach loop intended - not for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
typeof(ConfirmationPage).GetProperty(col.GetKey(i))
                        .SetValue(cp, col.Get(i), null);
```

Comment: Be careful doing it this way with AJAX-enabled pages.  Javascript frameworks often add extra parameters (like a timestamp) when you specify that you don't want cached responses.  That would break this code because you'd be looking for a parameter that doesn't correspond to a property on the class and thus get a NullReferenceException when the property isn't found.